# AJAX POST in same window instead of new

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I tried to make a contact form within a bootstrap modal.
An alert should show up right after submitting the form in the modal.
It is working fine on my site which I use for testing.
But when I integrate the code in my main site the alert is shown as text in a new window. Same code. Different response. What could cause this behavior?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                        <div class="messages"></div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">Name</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container-->
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'noreplay@xy.de'; 
$sendTo = 'webmaster@xy.de';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
```

});

Comment: Are you saying that in production it is showing the native browser's alert box?

Comment: Sorry if this is not clear. It is supposed to show a bootstrap alerts box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action parameter in form tag `action="contact.php"` is forcing the page to refresh try using this as form tag :-

```
<form id="contact-form">
```

and change `$(this).serialize()` in your ajax post code to :-

```
$('#contact-form').serialize()
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem :(
It just crashes the complete script. If I apply your changes I dont't recieve the correct message at all. Just some verry weird parts of the contacts.php

Comment: Try this don't make the second change that is don't change $(this).serialize()

Comment: But how is it supposed to work without the action and method tag? I thought they were important.

Comment: it is supposed to work because of these two lines :-
`type: "POST",
  url: url`

Comment: As keyword `type` in ajax code is equivalent to method and `url` is equivalent to `action`

Comment: I tried your idea but it didn't work.
But something interesting. It works absolutely fine if I put the modal with the form and the scripts into a subfolder of my website. What could cause that it is not working if I copy and paste it in the main site?